# Create Inbox rules by using the EWS Managed API

Tags: c#, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I am trying to create a rule by using EWS API for a shared mailbox. For that I am using the following code:

```
        Rule newRule = new Rule();            
        newRule.DisplayName = "Forward";
        forwardEmailTo= "xxx@hotmail.com";
        newRule.Conditions.SentToAddresses.Add("Forward", "sharedmailbox@myexchangedomain.online");
        newRule.Actions.ForwardToRecipients.Add(forwardEmailTo);
        CreateRuleOperation createMoveIfFromSalesRule = new CreateRuleOperation(newRule);
        service.UpdateInboxRules(new RuleOperation[] {createMoveIfFromSalesRule}, true);
```

But unfortunately the rule is not created on the shared mail box (sharedmailbox@myexchangedomain.online), it is being created on the principal mail box account.

What Am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UpdateInboxRules Method has an overload for the Mailbox you want to create the rule in so your method call should be

```
service.UpdateInboxRules(new RuleOperation[] {createMoveIfFromSalesRule,"TargetMailbxo@domain.com"}, true);
```

Comment: Thanks@Glen Scales . It worked. However the right overload is: service.UpdateInboxRules(new RuleOperation[] { createMoveIfFromSalesRule }, true, "TargetMailbxo@domain.com");